# mixed ltr and rtl within paragraph

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to use ltr and rtl content with different span inside single paragraph. It results in aligning the entire content in paragraph according to rtl. For instance, if my first span is rtl and second is ltr, then it ends up with second span appearing first and first span in the last.

In the following snippet you will see that in first list group time is appearing first which should have to appear second like shown in next group.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h2>List Group With Custom Content</h2>
    <div class="list-group">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">
        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">First List Group Item Heading</h4>
        <p class="list-group-item-text"><span>الفاتحہ.</span><span>0:11</span>
        </p>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Second List Group Item Heading</h4>
        <p class="list-group-item-text"><span>Fatiha</span><span>0:11</span>
        </p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `p` and `span` have a language-neutral directionality, so if there are no elements in the `p` that force a ltr direction, it will just take the natural direction for its whole content.

A possible solution is to change the last `span` in each `p` to a `bdo`, but I'm sure there are other, more elegant ones.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>List Group With Custom Content</h2>
  <div class="list-group">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">
      <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">First List Group Item Heading</h4>
      <p class="list-group-item-text"><span>الفاتحہ.</span><bdo dir="ltr">0:11</bdo>
      </p>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
      <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Second List Group Item Heading</h4>
      <p class="list-group-item-text"><span>Fatiha</span><bdo dir="ltr">0:11</bdo>
      </p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes... not compatible with chrome. Should be cross-browser compatible. :)

Comment: Through experimenting, I found a way that works in both Mozilla and Chrome. Hope this is not too much of a hack!

Comment: It doesn't work if I have a HTML form element like checkbox or button within paragraph.

Comment: Or if you can't, shall I remove this answer?